# 415 unsupported mediaType in POST request

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson

Was reading around and a lot of the issues others were having were Spring, Gradle, or something else. It seems that Postman does not like my request that I'm giving to my `POST` method.

Error:

```
b>description</b>
        <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type).</u>
```

Body from Postman:

```
{
"firstName": "firstName",
"lastName": "lastName",
"dob": "12/12/2012",
"address": "123 main st."
}
```

POST in question:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/createQuery")
public Response createQuery(ApplicationInfo info) throws IOException {
    String queryString =createStringFromJSON(info,true);
    queryMap.put(""+countId,queryString);
    countId++;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "";
    try {
        json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(queryMap);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        return Response.ok(json,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).entity(json).build();
}
```

Incredibly complex ApplicationInfo Object:

```
 public class ApplicationInfo

{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String dob;
    String address;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Hopefully someone more experienced can pinpoint the issue. Please keep it relevant to my issue.

Comment: This is a guess, but it might be complaining about the slashes in your dob variable..

Comment: Don't you think that the code ISSUING your request might be slightly pertinent to the question at hand?

Comment: No such luck @ryekayo these are all strings so it won't matter what's in there.

Comment: @MikeNakis could you explain further on your comment? I use Postman to issue the request.

Comment: Right but the JSON might have trouble passing through Tomcat because of the slashes

Comment: @ryekayo I did try it out just in case but no luck.

Comment: You say `It seems that Tomcat does not like my request that I'm giving to my POST method.`.  You have shown us everything except ***your request***.

Comment: Ah that's my error @MikeNakis I don't mean tomcat doesn't like it I mean that the response I get from Postman gives me a 415.

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Type on your request in Postman to application/json?

Comment: @BenHarris Yes I am. I triple checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @BenHarris for pointing me in the right direction. For all you future wanderers here is what you do:

If you are about where I am in your quest this is what you do:

add Jackson annotations to your pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>{$jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your `web.xml`:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.your.project; com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

So when you run Tomcat you're `ObjectMapper` will do its job for your request! Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your request body is valid json string, just verify if you have passed proper headers in postman app
Headers will look like

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but you're POSTing a string to a method which takes ApplicationInfo, and I'm not too sure JAX-RS does object mapping on the fly like Spring can do with @RequestBody.

Try changing your method signature to `public Response createQuery(String info) throws IOException` as your method is just trying to convert ApplicationInfo to JSON anyway.

Comment: I don't get the error anymore but I also don't get what I want. Do you know of anyway that I could use to pass in my object and avoid the error?

Comment: What do you want, and what are you getting? As far as I can tell your code just returns the json that was handed in, after adding it to a map.

Comment: Kind of, I'm trying to place all the fields in the object into one string. Which I format a certain way.

Comment: I want to take a request and turn it into one string.

Comment: Well, you could use an ObjectMapper such as GSON / Jackson to convert the JSON string you take in to your ApplicationInfo class, then just implement a toString method.

Comment: Assuming you're using Jersey there is some extra config you can do to handle object mapping automatically (keeping your original method signature), see this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: So instead of an object, I pass the json as a string and have jackson convert it? I can give that a try.

Comment: Yeah. The tutorial I linked above basically sets up the same thing but does it at a lower level (between the servlet request itself and your method being called).

Comment: You wouldn't by chance have an updated tutorial since would you? haha

Comment: Not really sorry - haven't used any of that myself, just googled it. Googling "Jersey JSON object mapping" should come up with some solid examples.

Comment: Thank you @BenHarris for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out I was missing Jackson Annotations! For future wanderers. Do this:

Comment: Hang on making an answer, can't delete comments!